# How to get the union/intersect/difference from two arrays of hashes and ignore some keys

Tags: ruby, arrays, union, intersect, hash

I want to get the union/intersect/difference from two arrays of hashes for example:

```
array1 = [{:name =>'Guy1', :age => 45},{:name =>'Guy2', :age => 45}]
array2 = [{:name =>'Guy1', :age => 45},{:name =>'Guy3', :age => 45}]
```

...

```
p array1 - array2 

=> [{:name=>"Guy2", :age=>45}]


p array2 - array1
=> [{:name=>"Guy3", :age=>45}]


p array1 | array2 
=> [{:name=>"Guy1", :age=>45}, {:name=>"Guy2", :age=>45}, {:name=>"Guy3", :age=>45}]
```

however when I want to only compare based on the names and ignore the ages without needing to remove them from the hashes for example:

```
array1 = [{:name =>'Guy1', :age => 45},{:name =>'Guy2', :age => 45}]
array2 = [{:name =>'Guy1', :age => 46},{:name =>'Guy3', :age => 45}]
```

In this case i'm not getting the results that I want b/c the ages are different.

```
array1 - array2 

=> [{:name=>"Guy1", :age=>45}, {:name=>"Guy2", :age=>45}]

array2 - array1
=> [{:name=>"Guy1", :age=>46}, {:name=>"Guy3", :age=>45}]

array1 | array2 
=> [{:name=>"Guy1", :age=>45}, {:name=>"Guy2", :age=>45}, {:name=>"Guy1", :age=>46}, {:name=>"Guy3", :age=>45}]
```

Is there a way to get the union/intersect/difference and ignore the age key?

edit: for a better example:

```
array1 = [{:name =>'Guy1', :age => 45},{:name =>'Guy2', :age => 45}]
array2 = [{:name =>'Guy1'},{:name =>'Guy3'}]

p array1 - array2
p array2 - array1
p array1 | array2
p array1 & array2
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is the expected result, especially what value for `:age`?

Comment: The expected result would be as if the `:age` didn't exist.

Comment: the expected result would be the same as in the first example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way of getting the union:

```
(array1 + array2).uniq{|a| a[:name]}
```

However, I would recommend creating your own subclass of `Hash` so you can safely override `eql?` as Cary Swoveland points out is what the set-like operators rely on. Note that you also need to limit the `hash` method to only provide the hashing function on the name field.

```
class Guy < Hash

  def eql?(other_hash)
    self[:name] == other_hash[:name]
  end

  def hash
    self[:name].hash
  end

end
```

Then these `Guy` objects will work in all of the set operations:

```
array1 = [ Guy[name:'Guy1', age: 45], Guy[name:'Guy2', age: 45] ]
array2 = [ Guy[name:'Guy1', age: 46], Guy[name:'Guy3', age: 45] ]

array1 - array2
#=> [{:name=>"Guy2", :age=>45}]

array2 - array1
#=> [{:name=>"Guy3", :age=>45}]

array1 | array2
#=> [{:name=>"Guy1", :age=>45}, {:name=>"Guy2", :age=>45}, {:name=>"Guy3", :age=>
45}]

array1 & array2
#=> [{:name=>"Guy1", :age=>45}]
```

Comment: Even subclassing can be dangerous, but, yes, better than fiddling with class `Hash`.  If `f` and `g` are `Guy` objects, one could inadvertently use `f.eql?(g)` when `f == g` was intended (changing `eql?` does not affect `=`), which could result in a fairly nasty bug.

Answer (score 0):

For the difference:

```
diff_arr = array1.map{|a| a[:name]} - array2.map{|a| a[:name]}

diff_arr.map{|a| array1.map{|s| s if s[:name] == a }}.flatten.compact
```

Intersection

```
intersec_arr = array1.map{|a| a[:name]} & array2.map{|a| a[:name]}

intersec_ar.map{|a| array1.map{|s| s if s[:name] == a }}.flatten.compact
```

Answer (score 0):

All three class `Array` methods referenced use [Hash#eql?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-eql-3F) to compare two elements that are both hashes.  (`Hash#eql?` checks to see if the hashcodes for the two hashes are equals.)  Therefore, we need only (temporarily) redefine `Hash#eql?`.

```
array1 = [{:name =>'Guy1', :age => 45}, {:name =>'Guy2', :age => 45}]
array2 = [{:name =>'Guy1'},             {:name =>'Guy3'}] 

class Hash
  alias old_eql? eql?
  def eql?(h) self[:name] == h[:name] end
end

array1 - array2
  #=> [{:name=>"Guy2", :age=>45}]
array2 - array1
  #=> [{:name=>"Guy3"}]
array1 | array2
  #=> [{:name=>"Guy1", :age=>45}, {:name=>"Guy2", :age=>45}, {:name=>"Guy3"}]
array1 & array2
  #=> [{:name=>"Guy1", :age=>45}]

class Hash
  alias eql? old_eql? # Restore eql?
  undef_method :old_eql?
end
```

Note that this is one of those few situations where `self` must be explicit.  If we wrote:

```
[:name] == h[:name]
```

instead of:

```
self[:name] == h[:name]
```

Ruby would assume that we are comparing the array `[:name]` with `h[:name]`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach due to the monkey patching of a core class `Hash`. However, if the OP were to create a new class, e.g. `class Guys < Hash` and override `eql?` then I would enthusiastically recommend this approach! (Perhaps you can edit/amend this answer?)

Comment: Also, this doesn't work. I think you're forgetting something (see my answer for a hint).

Comment: Good points, @Mark. I mainly put forward this solution because I thought it had educational value.  When writing it I knew I was skating on thin ice; I should have at least added some cautionary words.  Even subclassing `Hash` can be dangerous--as I will mention in a comment to your answer--but less so than tinkering with `Hash`.  I will address your second point in a separate comment.

Comment: @Mark, I noticed that the docs for all three methods, [Array#-](), `Array#|` and `Array#&` all the mention, "It compares elements using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency."  I know `Hash@eql?` uses `Hash#hash`, but it didn't make sense to me that the `Array` methods would depend on `Hash#hash` (as well as `Hash.eql?`), and I was too lazy to check the source code.  I concluded the sentence was just poorly worded.  Test results were OK without redefining `Hash#hash`.  Do you (or anyone else) know if `Hash#hash` needs to be redefined, and if so, why?

Comment: Yes, `Hash#hash` needs to be redefined. It didn't work for me any other way (in 1.9.3 irb). Here's a reference: http://javieracero.com/blog/the-key-to-ruby-hashes-is-eql-hash